# Laravel Auth::logout() not working properly

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to log out a user but it doesn't seem to be working...

```
public function logout() {

        $user = Auth::user();
        Auth::logout($user);

        return Redirect::to('/');
    }
```

If I comment out the first two lines, the redirect works...
But the logout part just doesn't.

Comment: Remove the `$user`parameter?

Comment: Didn't work.  If I log out, it errors out, yet when i press back and try to access any of the functionality it also errors out..so it looks like it is working, but its erroring where it shouldn't?

Comment: See the *manual* on the [line above the anchor here](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/security#manually) and [this example](http://laravel.io/forum/04-21-2014-authlogout) and plenty more... How much did you really try before asking here?

Comment: I dont think the issue is with logging out..its the erroring part thats confusing when i click logout.  Once i click it and use the back button I cant use any of the functionality a logged in user can use.  So it appears to be working, and frankly thats an  unneccassay question scowler

Answer (score 1):

Try to use **Auth::logout();** - without any parameters.

You might encounter an error saying that there is no **remember_token** field in your table, to fix this, find: **PROJECT_FOLDER/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/Guard.php** , then comment out line **520**.

Or you can fix this by adding a column 'remember_token' in your user table.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, yes -

Under the hood, the only thing that really needs to happen is `session_destroy()` -

As far as Laravel is concerned, this function exists in case there is any other clean up that needs to be done... for example, if a 'remember me' cookie needs to be deactivated...

But, to test your Laravel script, you could have a page - let's call it `sessionTest.php` -

```
<?php

echo "<pre>"; 
print_r($_SESSION); 


?>
```

If you visit this page before and after your logout - then you should have a better idea of what is going on.

If Laravel is really failing, it could be a Remember_me cookie that isn't being cleaned up properly, or some other strange issue that we would need to investigate further...

Comment: I dont think the issue is with logging out..its the erroring part thats confusing when i click logout. Once i click it and use the back button I cant use any of the functionality a logged in user can use. So it appears to be working